# writing out to stdout and followed by reading from stdin doesn't write to stdout in the same line - C Programming

Tags: c, io, stdin, system-calls

I'm writing a program where it involves creating a prompt that reads input from stdin. The actual code is large and the scope of this problem resides in the following snippet of code. Here's a simple layout of the code -

```c
char _buf[1];
while(*_buf!='q') { 
  printf(">>> ");
  read(0, _buf, 1);
}
```

when running the compiled code, I would expect the `stdout` to look something like the following -

```
>>> <stdin input>
```

but instead, nothing is being written out to `stdout`, or to be more specific, nothing in the same line of `stdin` is being shown. If I  add a `\n` at the end of the string output `>>>`, it enables it to show up in `stdout`, namely

```
>>>
<stdin input>
```

Now, I want to put up some constraints as to what i can and can not use. I just want to use the wrapper function `read()` to `read` syscall directly instead of using something like `fscanf(3)` or other similar libc functions.

If I modify the above code with only consisting of syscalls (e.g replacing `printf()` with `write()`). I do get the character string printed out before it is reading from stdin, likeso

```c
int main() {
    char _buf[1];
    while(*_buf!='q') {
        write(fileno(stdout),">>> ", 4);
        read(fileno(stdin),_buf,1);
        write(fileno(stdout), "\n", 1);
    }
}
```

but something unexpected happens, the char string `>>>`  is being printed out to stdout equal to the length of input is given to `stdin`.

```
>>> a
>>>
>>> aa
>>>
>>>
>>> aaa
>>>
>>>
>>>
```

given length 1 of input string, `a` prints out `>>>`  one time, `aa` 2 times, `aaa` 3 times and so on. I don't quite understand this behaviour. The expected behaviour is to only print `>>>`  followed by a read from `stdin`. Help me out doing this only using syscalls.

Comment: Well, you only `read` one character at a time. So every subsequent character you inputted is "triggering" another iteration of the loop (also remember the newline character!). As for the first issue, it is because `printf` is line-buffered by default.

Comment: @EugeneSh you say "by default", so is there any way or flags to disable line-buffering for `printf()`?

Comment: First issue: [*Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/2505965)

Comment: This can all be summarized as: if you wish to ensure a certain order of printing/scanning no matter functions, then use `fflush(stdout);` after each print.

Comment: Second issue: Write a nested loop that reads / writes until it reaches some terminating sentinel value (`'\n'`, `'q'`) ([cursory example](https://godbolt.org/z/fq3zMP1oo)). As Eugene says, you current write the prompt and the newline for *every* character read.